# Checking if color is already in used from array list C#

Tags: c#

Hello i would like to check if the certain color in my array is already used then
it will not use again. Im using currently random colors from the array, so sometimes it gets the same color.

```
// Add random block color
            Color[] colors = new Color[] { Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Green, Color.Purple, Color.Black, Color.Aqua };
            Random ra = new Random();
            int rnum = ra.Next(0, 5);
            p.block.brush_color = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, colors[rnum]));
// Add new generated process to list
            processes.Add(p);
```

How I can achieve this?

Comment: You will never get an Aqua color. See [Random.Next Method (Int32, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Use a list of colors and when one is used remove it from the list. The list length will be decreased by one each time.

Comment: How I can do that sir? Can you show me some example code?

Comment: I would suggest using `Queue<Color>` - add them in in random order, then dequeue as needed.

Comment: If you are going to use the Random class, create an instance once and call Next on it over again (I'm assuming that this code is executed more than once).  Instead of hard-coding the "5" in the `Next` call, consider using `colors.Length` (but taking into account what @LarsTech says).  You can't really "remove it from the list" as mentioned above - this is an array.  What you can do, however, is created a `Nullable<Color>[]` and null out the ones you have used.  If you get a null color, pull another one.  I'm assuming you are going to have more colors than 6.  Realize you'll run out quickly.

Comment: What do you want to do when all the colors have been used? I think what you really want is a way to shuffle your colors. Then you can take items from the list sequentially, and when you get to the last one, shuffle them again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Randomize a List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to handle this would be to shuffle the items in the array, then choose the items sequentially. The [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://www.dotnetperls.com/fisher-yates-shuffle) is typically regarded as the best algorithm for this:

```
private static Color[] colors =
{
    Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Green, Color.Purple, Color.Black, Color.Aqua
};

private static Random random = new Random();

private static void ShuffleColors()
{
    for (int index = 0; index < colors.Length; index++)
    {
        var randomIndex = index + random.Next(colors.Length - index);
        var temp = colors[randomIndex];
        colors[randomIndex] = colors[index];
        colors[index] = temp;
    }
}
```

But what happens when you get to the end of the array? It seems there are 3 possibilities:

1. Just start at the beginning again (but then you'll have a non-random pattern)
2. Shuffle the array and start at the beginning again
3. Shuffle the array but make sure the last color used is not the first item

I think the last one may be preferable, since it will give the most random output, so let's implement that one.

What we can do is keep track of the last index we displayed, and then when it represents the last item in the array, we can shuffle the array again. Then, before we continue, we want to check to make sure the first item in the array isn't the last item we displayed. If it is, then we swap it with some other random element, so we never have a repeating item.

```
private static int nextIndex = 0;

private static SolidBrush GetNextColoredBrush()
{
    // If we've displayed all the items, shuffle the deck
    if (nextIndex == colors.Length)
    {                
        var lastColorUsed = colors[nextIndex - 1];
        ShuffleColors();

        // If the first color is the same as the last color
        // we displayed, swap it with a random color
        if (colors[0].Name == lastColorUsed.Name)
        {
            var rndIndex = random.Next(1, colors.Length);
            colors[0] = colors[rndIndex];
            colors[rndIndex] = lastColorUsed;
        }

        // Reset our index tracker
        nextIndex = 0;
    }

    // Return the next color and increment our index
    return new SolidBrush(colors[nextIndex++]);
}
```

Now we can call this method in a loop to see what the output will look like:

```
private static void Main()
{
    // Output our random colors. Note that even though we
    // only we only have 6 colors, they are consistently 
    // output in a random order (but with no duplicates).
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetNextColoredBrush().Color.ToKnownColor());
    }


    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

Notice that there are no repeating elements until 6 have been displayed, and then the next six elements are in a different order:

[image]

**Usage in your code**

Oh, finally, to use this in your code, you would just do something like:

```
p.block.brush_color = GetNextColoredBrush();
```

However you may notice that I changed the output slightly so that it output a `KnownColor`. If you want to maintain your original code, you should modify the line that returns a value in the `GetNextColoredBrush` method:

```
return new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, colors[nextIndex++]));
```

Comment: Thank You for the effort sir, I use your code. But sometimes the color is repeating the same eventhough it has different block number. Check it: https://pasteboard.co/Hwk1K2T.png

Comment: Nevermind Sir. I alreahdy fix it, I mistakenly put the code. Thank You for your help +1 for you.

Answer (score 1):

Taking all the comments into account, how about something like:

```
Color[] colors = new Color[] { Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Green, Color.Purple, Color.Black, Color.Aqua };
List<Color> randomColors = new List<Color>();
var random = new Random();

//fill the queue with a bunch of colors, careful to take fewer than exist
do
{
    var index = random.Next(colors.Length);
    var newColor = colors[index];
    if (!randomColors.Contains(newColor))
    {
        randomColors.Add(newColor);
    }
} while (randomColors.Count < colors.Length - 2);

foreach (var color in randomColors)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(color.ToString());
}
```

If you have *many* colors, you might want to have a `HashSet<Color>` that you use to track your used colors (rather than traversing the list over and over (a lot)).

Comment: How I can insert this in my code sir? Im gonna use maximum of 6 colors only. Is it possible if i could not use random then I'll get the color by order from red to aqua? How I can do that?

Comment: If you just want six colors, shuffle them by hand and then use foreach to iterate over the array.

Answer (score 1):

There's multiple approaches you can take.

### Method 1 : Shuffle a List

Based on Rufus' link.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Color> ColorList = new List<Color>() { Colors.Red, Colors.Blue, Colors.Green, Colors.Pink };

    Shuffle(ColorList);

    while (ColorList.Count > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ColorList[0]);    // Equivalent of using the color.
        ColorList.RemoveAt(0);              // Remove from the list once used.
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void Shuffle<T>(IList<T> list)
{
    Random rng = new Random();

    int n = list.Count;
    while (n > 1)
    {
        n--;
        int k = rng.Next(n + 1);
        T value = list[k];
        list[k] = list[n];
        list[n] = value;
    }
}
```

This is not a bad method if you know you're going to work with only a handful of colors. Because this method works only for as many colors as you add and run the risk of running out of colors.

---

### Method 2 : Get a lot of colors.

You can create colors by specifying `R, G, B, and A` values of a color. First three corresponds to `Red, Green, and Blue` components of a color, and `A` which is `Alpha` is basically the opacity of color.

So you can create a color by

```
var color = Color.FromArgb(12, 23, 213, 44);
```

Here, range of each of the parameters is `0-255`.

Now, this method will give you a LOT of colors which you're unlikely to run out of. I put a limit of 16 between the increments just so you don't get too many similar colors.

```
private static List<Color> GetLotsOfColors(int gap)
{
    gap = gap < 16 ? 16 : gap;

    List<Color> ColorList = new List<Color>();
    for (int r = 0; r < 256; r += gap)
    {
        for (int g = 0; g < 256; g += gap)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < 256; b += gap)
            {
                for (int a = 0; a < 256; a += gap)
                {
                    ColorList.Add(Color.FromArgb((byte)a, (byte)r, (byte)g, (byte)b));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return ColorList;
}
```

Now you can use the previous `Shuffle()` method to shuffle them and then get them one by one.